# How to retrieve data from website with basic authentication?

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can I connect to a website with basic authentication? I'm using the http component. I saw somewhere, that `?username=&password=` is used, but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks to Ralf's answer I found out that I forgot to add `authMethod` to the url. Here is the solution:

```
http://localhost/?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=username&authPassword=password
```

Comment: since most sites use a POST method for login.. your query string approach might not work.

Comment: @DeepakMishra POST authentication is not the same thing as HTTP BASIC authentication. That has a specific technical meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [http compoment](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) documentation the following should work:

```
http://...?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=...&authPassword=...
```

Be aware of the security implications of using basic auth without SSL/TLS.

Comment: It works. I've forgot to add authMethod=Basic. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [this](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) page and look down for the header "Authentication and Proxy". There you may find the following documented - `authMethod`, `authUsername` and `authPassword`. To use it I'd do something like this

```
String authUsername = "MyUser";
String authPassword = "MyPass";
HttpComponent http = new HttpComponent();

HttpConfiguration config = http.getHttpConfiguration();
config.setAuthMethod(AuthMethod.Basic);
config.setAuthUsername(authUsername);
config.setAuthPassword(authPassword);
http.setHttpConfiguration(config);
```

Comment: I saw that page, but I'm really new in apache camel and I don't understand how to set these options to the HttpEndpoint. Can you please provide an example.

Comment: How can I add that to the apache camel context?